# How to replace some specific characters in django template?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

Some values from database get fetched and passed to the template like this :`['2']`

In controller :

```
book = Book.objects.get(id=id)
return render(request, 'file.html', {'book': book})
```

In template:

```
{{book.pages}}
```

output :
`['140']`

Book model :

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=False, default='', null=True)
    cover_url = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    pages = models.CharField(max_length=6, unique=False, default='', null=True)
```

How to delete brackets and `'` before delivering the result?

Comment: Can you share the `Book` model. It looks like you have made it an array. So it is not good to simple remove the surrounding characters: what would you do for an empty list, a list with two or more elements?

Comment: Where is you book models code

Comment: Show your models and your views code please !

Comment: no its not an array. it is just a prepopulated string in the database